# Audio issues - noise when playing any sort of sounds, even when volume is at 0%

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa, pipewire

Edit: It looks like it also happens with normal speakers, I just can't hear it unless I get close to them

I've had this problem occur on every single distro that I tried. I have a realtek sound card in my asus g551vw, but am using the drivers from intel (kernel) since the ones from realtek are ancient (2018) and use an even older kernel (there is a warning to only use kernel 3.18 or LOWER ? (I tried compiling it and as expected, it doesn't compile anymore)

Edit2: Forgot to mention: I have dual boot with windows and it only happens in linux, so it can't be a hardware issue

In the following link someone had the exact same problem but I don't know how to use that fix though. Does anyone have any idea how to fix the problem?

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=262720

Btw I'm using Pipewire and do not have PulseAudio installed.

In the following link I posted a recording (.mp3) of the issue. It is silent until I start a video/something that plays audio, then a loud pop and white noise until a couple seconds after I stop the video.
https://www.file.io/74YT/download/dIulDyzgACUh

A couple months ago I tried the "fix" that completly disables the power save and all that did is to make the noise constant, which was worse.

Loopback is disabled in alsamixer.

I should also mention that the pop and noise are independent from the volume. (volume = 0, still happens at the same exact loudness)

I believe the driver is boosting the output, and since lowering the volume in alsamixer doesn't help, I'm guessing this is a driver level issue maybe?

pactl list sinks shows me this:Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec .

- `uname -a =`

  ```
  Linux archlinux 5.17.7-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 12 May 2022 18:55:54 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- `lscpi -vvv =`

  ```
  00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
  Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1d3d
  Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
  Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Latency: 32
  Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 132
  Region 0: Memory at df328000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
  Region 4: Memory at df300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
  Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
  ```